# Difference between GALIS and NEF/SPA?

Tags: theoretical-neuroscience, nef, spa

The Gated Attractors Learning Instruction Sequences (GALIS) framework, used to solve a [card-matching task](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893608016300028), as well as [the n-back task](https://cgis.cs.umd.edu/~jared/2013-NN-sylvester.pdf), appears to be trying to unite high-level symbolic reasoning to neural networks. This is also the goal of the NEF/SPA.

What are the differences in approach and what trade-offs exist?